# why enter event on every textbox run the first button click

Tags: asp.net

I'm working with asp.net and c#, in his case I have two textbox and two imgbuttons but both run the
first button click when i do enter key in any textbox  i need to
execute any button click depends of the enter i do on any textbox

and I´m using this code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCodCliente" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="89px"> 
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imbtnConsultaCliente" src="Images/Search.png" 
runat="server" Height="16px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click1" Width="17px" 
ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" /> 


<asp:TextBox ID="txtMaterial" onkeypress="continues()" autofocus="autofocus"   
runat="server" Width="64px"  ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:ImageButton ID="btnBuscaSku"  src="Images/Search.png" runat="server" 
Height="16px" Width="17px" OnClick="btnBuscaSku_Click"/>
</form>


protected void ImageButton1_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
//Action
}

protected void btnBuscaSku_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
//Action
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you only have one `DefaultButton` for the `form` so whenever you hit enter key the default button click event gets triggered. In order to make relevant button call wrap your markup inside an `asp:panel` control and set `DefaultButton` for individual panels.
Your markup should look like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="imbtnConsultaCliente">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCodCliente" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="89px"> 
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imbtnConsultaCliente" src="Images/Search.png"
            runat="server" Height="16px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click1" Width="17px"
            ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />

    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnBuscaSku">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaterial" onkeypress="continues()" autofocus="autofocus"
            runat="server" Width="64px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnBuscaSku" src="Images/Search.png" runat="server"
            Height="16px" Width="17px" OnClick="btnBuscaSku_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey bro, thank you so much, it works such as you said

Comment: Don't forget to upvote or mark it as the accepted answer if it was helpful for you. @danielvasquez